# VBA MACRO unable to paste

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Please help me... this is driving me nuts.

I am trying to copy some data from a CSV but unable to paste it to the destination file that I normally do manually.

The issue I am facing:
-I cannot go back to the destination file's sheet
-Even if I could it would paste as string
-I need the data to be identical from the CSV

```
 MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    ChDir "C:\datafolder\"

    Application.Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Windows("chickenfeed.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Export").Range("A1").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End sub
```

Comment: How about to add following code , "ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True", at end of program (as a line just above the ’End Sub' )　？

Answer (score 1):

You closed the source range before the paste.

Try this and learn the flow...
(Assuming it's "**Sheet1**" you try to copy data from)

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteData()
    Dim oSourceWB As Workbook, oTargetWB As Workbook, MyFile As String

    MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    ChDir "C:\datafolder\"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set oTargetWB = Workbooks("chickenfeed.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not (oSourceWB Is Nothing And oTargetWB Is Nothing) Then
        oSourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy oTargetWB.Sheets("Raw Export").Range("A1")
        oSourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    Set oSourceWB = Nothing
    Set oTargetWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx PatricK, But I ran into a similar problem with the copy and paste part.

'oSourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy oTargetWB.Sheets("Raw Export").Range("A1")

Comment: What are you trying to copy from the source? `UsedRange`?